# Unsure How to Change Limits of Integration

Tags: calculus

I've been trying to solve an integral (part of a step in calculating the Fisher Information of a Cauchy Random Variable):

$$\frac{-2}{\pi a^3} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{r}{(1 + (\frac{r}{a})^2)^2} \, dr$$

I started by trying to use u-substitution:

Let $u = 1 + (\frac{r}{a})^2 \;\; du = \frac{2r}{a^2}dr$

$$\frac{-1}{\pi a} \int_{u_1}^{u_2} \frac{1}{u^2} \, du$$

My question: How do I change the limits of integration (aka: find $u_1$ and $u_2$)? Plugging in the original limits of $-\infty$ and $\infty$ into my equation for $u$ leaves me with questions regarding the nature of squaring $-\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your transformation *is not injective*; the change of variables formula accordingly fails and leaves with an integral from $\infty\to\infty$. Meaningless. That said, we can immediately note the integrand is odd hence the integral, as it clearly is convergent, must equal to $0$.

If the integrand were strictly even then you could truncate it to an integral from $0\to\infty$, and then your $u$-substitution would be a good start.